# Computing a curve on a surface which has constant geodesic curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

The paper [Computation of Shortest Paths on Free-Form Parametric Surfaces](https://web.mit.edu/deslab/pubs/geo.pdf) shows how to compute a geodesic curve on a surface. In this paper they start with two equations which are true for a geodesic curve on a surface (eqn 14):

$\frac{dt}{ds} \cdot r_u = 0, \frac{dt}{ds} \cdot r_v = 0$

From here the paper goes on to transform these equations into two second order differential equations (eqn 17-18):

$\frac{d^2u}{ds^2} + \Gamma^1_{11}(\frac{du}{ds})^2 + 2 \Gamma^1_{12}\frac{du}{ds}\frac{dv}{ds} + \Gamma^1_{22}(\frac{dv}{ds})^2 = 0$

$\frac{d^2v}{ds^2} + \Gamma^2_{11}(\frac{du}{ds})^2 + 2 \Gamma^2_{12}\frac{du}{ds}\frac{dv}{ds} + \Gamma^2_{22}(\frac{dv}{ds})^2 = 0$

Finally they rewrite as a system of first order differential equations (eqn 19-22) which can be solved using the finite difference method.

$\frac{du}{ds} = p$

$\frac{dv}{ds} = q$

$\frac{dp}{ds} = -\Gamma^1_{11}p^2 - 2\Gamma^1_12pq - \Gamma^1_{22}q^2$

$\frac{dq}{ds} = -\Gamma^2_{11}p^2 - 2\Gamma^2_12pq - \Gamma^2_{22}q^2$

I have implemented this paper in code and it is working well. What I want to do is extend the method to compute a curve of **constant** geodesic curvature, or even a **curvature which depends on the magnitude of the normal curvature**.

Is there a way to adapt the initial equations to achieve this?

---

**Update 11 Jan (Ted Shifrin)**

The paper has equation (6) which I believe is what you wrote:

$\kappa_g = \frac{dt}{ds} \cdot (N \times t)$

It goes on to write this equation as (11):

$\kappa_g = [\Gamma^2_{11}(\frac{du}{ds})^3 + (2\Gamma^2_{12} - \Gamma^1_{11})(\frac{du}{ds})^2\frac{dv}{ds} + (\Gamma^2_{22} - \Gamma^1_{12})\frac{du}{ds}(\frac{dv}{ds})^2 - \Gamma^1_{22}(\frac{dv}{ds})^3 + \frac{du}{ds}\frac{d^2v}{ds^2} - \frac{d^2u}{ds^2}\frac{dv}{ds}]\sqrt{EG - F^2}$

When I try to write this as a system of first order ODEs I end up with:

$\frac{du}{ds} = p$

$\frac{dv}{ds} = q$

$\frac{dp}{ds} = 
-\Gamma^2_{11} \frac{p^3}{q} -
(2\Gamma^2_{12} - \Gamma^1_{11}) p^2 -
(2\Gamma^2_{22} - \Gamma^1_{12}) p q +
\Gamma^1_{22} q^2 + 
\frac{p}{q}\frac{dq}{ds} - 
\frac{\kappa_g}{q \sqrt{EG - F^2}}$

$\frac{dq}{ds} = \Gamma^2_{11} p^2 +
(2\Gamma^2_{12} - \Gamma^1_{11}) p q +
(2\Gamma^2_{22} - \Gamma^1_{12}) q^2 -
\Gamma^1_{22} \frac{q^3}{p} +
\frac{q}{p} \frac{dp}{ds} + 
\frac{\kappa_g}{p \sqrt{EG - F^2}}$

I am not sure how to go forward. $\frac{dp}{ds}$ depends on $\frac{dq}{ds}$. This means I cannot calculate my $F$ function in the finite difference method.

In the paper they seem to suggest I can use the first fundamental form to fix this?

Comment: These formulas are all totally standard undergraduate differential geometry material. Have you looked at some standard textbooks to find the formula for geodesic curvature? Not surprisingly, specifying a nonzero quantity will be more involved than specifying zero. You will need to project the acceleration vector onto the tangent plane; in particular, to get the sign, you will need to project onto the vector $\mathbf n\times\mathbf T$, where $\mathbf n$ is the surface normal and $\mathbf T$ is the unit tangent to the curve. But you must make sure that $s$ really is an arclength parameter.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your comment. I have been reading Differential geometry of curves and surfaces by Manfredo P do Carmo to try and understand these ideas. 

I have updated the question based on what you wrote.